# Ocaml Type Error For enumerate example

Tags: f#, functional-programming, ocaml

Hello I am new to OCaml And I am trying to learn the basic syntax of tail recursion. I wrote the following code in order to get a list and return the list with duples containing element and its index. for example
["b";"c";"dd";] -> [("b", 0); ("c", 1); ("dd", 2)]

I wrote the following code:

```
let enumerateWithTail lst =
  let rec inside lst acc index =
  match lst with
  | [] -> acc
  | x::xs -> inside xs (x,index)::acc (index+1)
 in inside lst [] 0;;
```

This doesn't work but my professors example(which at least I think its pretty similar) works. My professors code is:

```
let enumerate lst =
  let rec aux lst acc =
    match lst with
    | [] -> acc
    | x::xs -> let (eList, index) = acc
               in aux xs ((x, index)::eList, index+1)
  in List.rev(fst(aux lst ([], 0)))
```

Can someone please explain why my code gives the error: 
This expression has type 'a * 'b
       but an expression was expected of type 'c list

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is with precedence. Function application has higher precedence than any operator, including `::`, so this:

```
inside xs (x,index)::acc (index+1)
```

is interpreted as:

```
(inside xs (x,index)) :: (acc (index+1))
```

whereas what you want is:

```
inside xs ((x,index)::acc) (index+1)
```

Comment: This precedence issue has come up repeatedly here on SO recently. Teachers of OCaml should take note; it might be something to explain early on.